# Does clicking on a JTextField call the actionPerformed method

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I have multiple `JTextField`s and I want to see which one is selected within the program. At the moment it does not seem as though clicking on the `JTextField` calls an `ActionEvent` (is that how you phrase it?).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if(e.getSource().equals(JTextField.class)){
        current = (JTextField) e.getSource();
        System.out.println(current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ActionListener` will generally be triggered when the user "actions" the field, for most platforms/look and feels, this is triggered by the user pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

I think what you're after is a `FocusListener`

Have a look at [How to Write a Focus Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) for more details

If you just want to find out which component is currently focused, you could use the `KeyboardFocusManager`

```
Component focusedComponent = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very simple and direct

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `addMouseListener` too,

```
jtextField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        ...
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the actionListener to the JTextFiled?

```
JTextField tf= new JTextfield();
tf.addActionListener(//class name goes there, if the actionListener is in a different class otherwise just say "this");
```

Comment: I did this. This does not call an ActionEvent